# Validating HTML input elements inside a DIV (visible wizard step) which is inside a FORM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, wizard

I have decided to create a wizard form in HTML 5 (actually using ASP.NET MVC here). I have the following HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="wizard-step">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="first name" />
    </div>
    <div class="wizard-step">
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="last name" />
    </div>
    <div class="wizard-step">
        <input type="text" name="suffix" placeholder="suffix" />
    </div>

    <button class="back-button" type="button">
        Back</button>
    <button class="next-button" type="button">
        Next</button>
}
```

Then I have this js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $steps = $(".wizard-step");
        var index = 0;

        var count = $steps.length;
        $steps.each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        $(".back-button").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var $currentStep = $steps.first();

        $currentStep.show();
        $currentStep.addClass("current-step");

        $(".back-button").click(function () {
            $currentStep.hide();
            $currentStep.removeClass("current-step");
            $currentStep = $currentStep.prev();
            $currentStep.addClass("current-step");
            $currentStep.show();
            index--;
            $(".next-button").removeAttr("disabled");
            if (index == 0) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });

        $(".next-button").click(function () {
            var $inputFields = $(".current-step :input");

            var hasError = false;
            $inputFields.each(function () {
                if (!validator.element(this)) {
                    hasError = true;
                }
            });

            if (hasError)
                return false;

            index++;
            $(".back-button").removeAttr("disabled");
            if (index == count - 1) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            }

            $currentStep.hide();
            $currentStep.removeClass("current-step");
            $currentStep = $currentStep.next();
            $currentStep.addClass("current-step");
            $currentStep.show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically, what I want is upon clicking the Next button, it will validate the input elements found inside the current visible DIV, not the entire FORM. Is it possible to do this using HTML5? If not, maybe jQuery?

If you have others in mind, please do share it here. Many many thanks!

Comment: I have to say, after just a quick glance over your code, it appears that when you click the Next button, it only validates the inputs inside the ".current-step" div, not the entire form.  Isn't this what you want?

Comment: yes, that is what i need. the current script is not working as expected.

Comment: I suppose it depends heavily on what `validator.element(this)` does... do you have this code available?

Comment: actually i have that line located at the $(".next-button").click.

Comment: ?  where is `validator` implemented?

Comment: oh i get that. actually i dont have     validator implemented yet which is the reason of the script throwing an error. do you have some samples how to define one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some playing with the jquery i happened to find the solution despite of lack of samples and tutorials in validation. inside the $(".next-button").click() block, i made these changes:

old:

```
var hasError = false;
$inputFields.each(function () {
   if (!validator.element(this)) {
      hasError = true;
   }
});

if (hasError)
   return false;
```

new:

```
var isValid = false;
$inputFields.each(function () {
  isValid = $(this).valid();
});

if (!isValid)
return false;
```

======================

i could also add this right under the $(document).ready() line to use/add jquery validation rules:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
  rules: {
    lastname: "required"
  }
});
```